# Android Studio App crashes after adding code for Bluetooth Connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Im currently working at an app for controlling an arduino via bluetooth. I added some Activitys for menus and so on. Yesterday I added a new Activity for connecting my device to the bluetooth module.

Is it even possible to connect to the device in one activity and actually controlling (sending letters) it in another Activity?

With that said the app crashes every time I try to open the activity with the bluetooth code in it. Every other Activity works without any problem.

I hope somebody can help.

Here is my Code:

MainActivity.java  (the activity which will control the module):

```
package com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //MENÜPUNKTE
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent settingsintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                settingsactivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsintent);
                return false;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_connect) {
        Intent connectintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                connectactivity.class);
                startActivity(connectintent);
                return false;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


//SeekBars

private SeekBar seekBarGas;
private TextView textViewGas;

private SeekBar seekBarSteering;
private TextView textViewSteering;

private CheckBox backwards_checkBox;
boolean rückwärts_var = false;

boolean safeMode;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    seekBarGas = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGas);
    textViewGas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGas);
    seekBarGas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textViewGas.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarGas.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBarGas.setProgress(0);
        }
    });

    seekBarSteering = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSteering);
    textViewSteering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSteering);
    seekBarSteering.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textViewSteering.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarSteering.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBarSteering.setProgress(3);
        }
    });


    //GET DATA Settings

    Intent safeMode_Intent = getIntent();
    safeMode = safeMode_Intent.getBooleanExtra("safeMode", false);


    //Rückwärts

    CheckBox backwards_checkBox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.backwards_checkBox);

    backwards_checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rückwärts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                rückwärts_var = true;

                if (safeMode == true) {
                    seekBarGas.setMax(2);
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vorwärts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                rückwärts_var = false;

                if (safeMode == true){
                seekBarGas.setMax(5);
                }
        }
    }
        });


    //Bluetooth



    if (btAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth wird auf diesem Gerät nicht unterstützt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }






}





}
```

BT_Classic.java (the activity which connects to the module) :

```
package com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;


public class BT_Classic extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button pairedButton;
private Button discoveredButton;
private Button btonButton;
private Button btoffButton;
ListView list;

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLED = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE = 0;

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt__classic);

    pairedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pairedButton);
    discoveredButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discoveredButton);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list) ;



    //Pairing Button

    pairedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices){
                devices.add(bt.getName());
            }

            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(BT_Classic.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devices);
            list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });

    discoveredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                Intent bton = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(bton, REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            }


        }
    });

    btonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bton = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(bton, REQUEST_ENABLED);
        }
    });

    btoffButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btAdapter.disable();
        }
    });










}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Bluetooth Car"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".connectactivity"
        android:label="Connect"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".settingsactivity"
        android:label="Settings"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BT_LE"
        android:label="Connect Bluetooth Low Energy"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".BT_Classic"
        android:label="Connect Bluetooth Classic"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        ></activity>
</application>
```

build.gradle (Module:app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar"
    minSdkVersion '16'
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

Crashlog:

```
2018-09-12 17:25:36.957 10178-10178/com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar, PID: 10178
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  


ComponentInfo{com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar/com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar.BT_Classic}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
        at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at 
    com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar.BT_Classic.onCreate(BT_Classic.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Comment: Show us the logcat for the error when it crash... Also, not related to your problem the name of the classes needs to start with Uppercase. I'm telling you this because of **connectActivity** and **settingsActivty**

Comment: I updated the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btonButton` and `btoffButton` are not initialized and equals null.

You should initialize them with `findViewById()` like you do with pairedButton

```
btonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.put_here_btn_on_id);
btoffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.put_here_btn_off_id);
```

Comment: Thanks that actually was the issue. I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 1):

btonButton and btoffButton have not been initialised yet and then you are calling `setonClickListener` this causes `NPE`

Inside `onCreate` initialise like this:

```
btonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btonButton);
btoffButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btoffButton);
```